# ERROR: Touchable child must either be native or forward setNativeProps to a native component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am currently doing ReactNative course from coursera and the course is 4 years old and i am facing this error: Touchable child must either be native or forward setNativeProps to a native component.

I've no idea what this is. It will be greatly helpful if someone will help me.Adding files details as well:

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Main from './components/MainComponent';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Main />
    );
  }
}
```

MainComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Menu from './MenuComponent';
import { DISHES } from '../shared/dishes';
import Dishdetail from './DishdetailComponent';
import { View } from 'react-native';

class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dishes: DISHES,
      selectedDish: null,
    };
  }

  onDishSelect(dishId) {
    this.setState({selectedDish: dishId})
}

  render() {
    return (
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <Menu dishes={this.state.dishes} onPress={(dishId) => this.onDishSelect(dishId)} />
            <Dishdetail dish={this.state.dishes.filter((dish) => dish.id === this.state.selectedDish)[0]} />
        </View>
    );
  }
}
  
export default Main;
```

MenuComponent.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';

function Menu(props) {

    const renderMenuItem = ({item, index}) => {
        return (
            <View>
                <ListItem
                key={index}
                title={item.name}
                subtitle={item.description}
                hideChevron={true}
                onPress={() => props.onPress(item.id)}
                leftAvatar={{ source: require('./images/uthappizza.png')}}
                />
            </View>
        );
    };

    return (
            <View>

            <FlatList 
                data={props.dishes}
                renderItem={renderMenuItem}
                keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
                />
                </View>
    );
}


export default Menu;
```

Dishdetailcomponent.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Card } from 'react-native-elements';


function Dishdetail(props) {
    return(
        <View >
            <RenderDish dish={props.dish} />
        </View>
    );
}

function RenderDish(props) {
    
    const dish = props.dish;
        if (dish != null) {
            return(
                <View>
                    <Card 
                    featuredTitle={dish.name}
                    image={require('./images/uthappizza.png')}>
                        <Text style={{margin: 10}}>
                            {dish.description}
                        </Text>
                    </Card>
                </View>
            );
        }
        else {
            return(<View></View>);
        }
}

export default Dishdetail;
```

Help will be appreciated!!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue some days before. Quickfix for this issue.

```
import TouchableOpacity form 'react-native';
```

Add following in the MenuComponent.js

```
<ListItem 
            Component={TouchableOpacity}
            key={item.id}
            title={item.name}
            subtitle={item.description}
            hideChevron={true}
            onPress={() => props.onPress(item.id)}
            leftAvatar={{ source: require('./images/uthappizza.png')}}
        />
```

and run the program again. This will fix your problem.